# Loading resources using java web start

Tags: java, swing, applet, java-web-start, embedded-resource

Just uploaded a java web start application to my website. It launches fine and everything but doesnt load any of the resources. How do I change the resource paths in my java code or JNLP file so that it loaded the resources used with the program? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[mentioned here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html)

The tutorial mentioned how to load resource.

Comment: I have my resources hosted on my website. I have them in my program right now the same as the tutorial. I think its different when they are hosted right? Thats what I am looking for. Thanks,

Comment: Ok, could you check the permission of your resource and if possible could you post your code or JNLP file. I faced the same issue and it was merely permission of the file.